# Booleans in Squeryl dynamic queries

Tags: scala, squeryl

I'm trying to use Squeryl (0.9.4 for scala 2.8.1) dynamic queries (`.?` and `inhibitWhen(...)`). They are working fine while I'm using String/Int/whatever fields, but seem to interfere with squeryl's syntax sugar for boolean conditions.

Assuming we have a `is_trusted: Option[Boolean]` defined somewhere, the following code

```
where ( obj => 
  obj.is_trusted === is_trusted.?
)
```

does not compile, throwing the following error:

```
... type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.squeryl.dsl.ast.LogicalBoolean
[error]  required: org.squeryl.dsl.NonNumericalExpression[org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode.BooleanType]
[error]     obj.is_trusted === is_trusted.?
[error]                                   ^
```

even this one does not work, failing on the first condition:

```
where ( obj => 
  obj.is_trusted.inhibitWhen(is_trusted == Some(true)) and
  not(obj.is_trusted).inhibitWhen(is_trusted == Some(false))
)
```

The only working version uses double `not` as a hint for the compiler:

```
not(not(obj.is_trusted)).inhibitWhen(is_trusted != Some(true)) and
not(obj.is_trusted).inhibitWhen(is_trusted != Some(false))
```

Is there a more sane way to do dynamic queries with booleans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... I think this is probably another bug caused by an implicit conversion from Boolean -> LogicalBoolean.  That feature has been deprecated in 0.9.5 because of issues similar to this.  What the .? should do is trigger an implicit conversion from Boolean -> BooleanExpression but since LogicalBoolean has a .? method as well there is a conflict and the latter appears to be have precedence.  I know it's not terribly pretty, but try this:

```
where ( obj => 
  obj.is_trusted === is_trusted.~.?
)
```

The .~ should force the conversion to BooleanExpression[Option[Boolean]] before .? is invoked.

Comment: Happy to help.  If you have any problems in the future you may want to consider posting them at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/squeryl.  Max, Squeryl's creator, tends to respond pretty quickly.